# What is the fastest way to retrieve a million records from an SQLite database file and display it in the WPF Datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, sqlite

I have an SQLite3 Database file, `MyDatabase.sqlite` having a million rows and 50 columns (File size ~200MB). I want to load the data from this file and display it on a WPF `Datagrid`.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand("Select * from Orders", conn))
{
    using (IDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        dt.Load(rdr);
    }
}
```

It takes around 54 seconds to execute. `SQLiteAdapter.Fill(dataset)` also takes the same amount of time. Is there a faster way to fetch data from SQLite DB ?

Comment: What exactly would a user *even do or want with* 50 million fields? Load only what you need the user to interact with as and when needed.

Comment: how would this be useful to a human? it screams information overload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to select the sql table chunk by chunk.
For Example (top 200 then second 200 and etc.). Just find a number where you are comfortable.
You can do this by simply using `ROW_NUMBER` in SQL transact which has good documentation and example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/53440/How-To-Select-Record-Based-on-Row-Number).

After you re-query a new chunk of data from the database, add new row to the data table using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ycd1034.aspx).

Comment: How is reading the data in chunks using multiple queries better than using one query?

Comment: It would _seem_ faster to the user. And actually be a little slower.

Comment: Only if you also display the data in chunks.

Comment: So sorry, my answer wasn't very complete . When you requery, use add row to data table.